How can I repair a gouge in a painted interior steel railing?
A contractor used our staircase railing to put down a makeshift scaffold without our permission. It gouged out the top of the railing!
Is this cosmetic damage, or more serious? What if anything can be done to fix this? The house is originally from the 70s.


That looks like a welded steel railing. It's unlikely that structural damage was done. You'll need to smooth the surface and repaint. Unfortunately I get the impression that soft paint, like a latex for walls, was used. That can make sanding more challenging.
Start with a sandpaper in hand or a soft sanding block having grit around 180. See if you can sand without the paint shredding further. If it does you may need to use a filler instead, or you may need to strip the entire railing. If you're able to sand successfully, finish with a higher grit, like 220.
When you paint, if you don't have leftover original paint, cover an entire component, like the top rail. Color and sheen are likely to vary enough that a patch job will look like a patch, but if you stop at a corner, for example, it'll be less conspicuous.
If you are buying new paint, use an enamel for metal, not a wall latex. It'll be much more durable.
